# Is locking instance or member based

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

I have a question about locking in c#. Does c# lock an instance of an object, or the member.

If i have the following code:

```
lock(testVar)
{
    testVar = testVar.Where(Item => Item.Value == 1).ToList();
    //... do some more stuff
}
```

Does c# keep the lock, even i set `testVar` to a new value?

Comment: Why do you need to reassign the lock?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin what to you mean with reassign the lock? I reassign `testVar`.

Comment: Why do you use a variable that you're working with as a lock?

Comment: Check the msdn article on locks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin i've read the article already, but could not find the answer in it.

Comment: Have you read this `Best practice is to define a private object to lock on, or a private static object variable to protect data common to all instances.`?

Comment: Yes, i have read it and i understand it. But how is this the answer to my question? It's an best practice.

Comment: If that's the best practice, why are you not using it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All C# objects inherit from `System.Object`, which itself always contains 4 bytes dedicated to be used when you use the syntactic sugar for `lock`. That's called a *SyncBlock object*.

When you create a new object using `new`, in your case, `ToList` which generated a new reference to a `List<T>`, you're actually **overriding** the old reference, which invalidates your `lock`. That means that now multiple threads could *possibly* be inside your `lock`. The compiler will transform your code into a `try-finally` block with an extra local variable, to avoid you from shooting your leg.

That is why the best practice is to define a **dedicated private readonly variable** which will act as a sync root object, instead of using a class member. That way, your intentions are clear to anyone reading your code.

**Edit:**

There is a [nice article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx) which describes the objects structure in memory:

> SyncTableEntry also stores a pointer to **SyncBlock** that contains useful
>   information, but is rarely needed by all instances of an object. This
>   information includes the object's lock, its hash code, any thunking
>   data, and its AppDomain index. For most object instances, there will
>   be no storage allocated for the actual SyncBlock and the syncblk
>   number will be zero. This will change when the execution thread **hits
>   statements like lock(obj) or obj.GetHashCode.**

[image: Object in memory representation]

Comment: Thank you for the pricture, if i could, i would give +1 again.

Comment: @BendEg Glad to help. I've added a link to the MSDN article. You should read it, has great internal insights.

Answer (score 4):

It locks on the object that the expression (`testVar`) resolves to. This means that your code does have a thread race, because once the list is reassigned, other concurrent threads could be locking on the *new* instance.

A good rule of thumb: only ever `lock` on a `readonly` field. `testVar` clearly isn't... but it *could be*, especially if you use `RemoveAll` to change the existing list instead of creating a new one. This of course depends on *all* access to the list happening inside the `lock`.

Frankly, though, most code **doesn't need to be thread-safe**. If code *does* need to be thread safe, the supported use scenarios must be clearly understood by the implementer.

Answer (score 1):

The `lock` expression translates to a `try/finally` expression using `Monitor.Enter/Monitor.Exit`. 
Doing a simple test with some code similar to yours (with VS2015 Preview) you can see what the compiler translates the code to.

The code

```
var testVar = new List<int>();
lock (testVar)
{
    testVar = new List<int>();
    testVar.Add(1);
}
```

Is actually translated to this:

```
List<int> list2;
List<int> list = new List<int>();
bool lockTaken = false;
try
{
    list2 = list;
    Monitor.Enter(list2, ref lockTaken);
    list = new List<int> { 1 };
}
finally
{
    if (lockTaken)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(list2);
    }
}
```

So you can see that the compiler has completely removed your variable `testVar` and replaced it with 2 variables, namely `list` and `list2`. Then the following happens:

1. `list2` is initialized to `list` and now both references point to the same instance of `List<int>`.
2. The call `Monitor.Enter(list2, ref lockTaken)` associates the synchronization block in the `List<int>` object with the current thread.
3. The `list` variable is assigned to a new instance of `List<int>`, but `list2` still points to the original instance that we locked against.
4. The lock is release using `list2`

So even though you think that you are changing the lock variable, you are actually not. Doing that however makes your code hard to read and confusing so you should use a dedicated lock variable as suggested by the other posts.